# React-Hook-Form and preventDefault on handleSubmit

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I've been using ReactHookForm (RHF) for a while now and i'm fairly happy with it. I'm by no means a pro though.

I currently have a page with multiple seperate forms on it. When ever you submit the form and use RHF's handleSubmit i get a page reload. It looks to me like i need to be able to e.preventDefault() on the submit event. BUT, i cant seem to access the event for the submit. Has anyone else had this issue and if so can someone help please.

Answer (score 0):

ok, so this wasnt documented (or rather i didnt see this mentioned in the documentation)

But when you use RHF's handleSubmit it sends the values of the form && a synthetic base event.

So you can do something like this:

```
const someForm = () => {

    const { handleSubmit } = useForm();
    
    const formSubmit = (values, event) => {
        event.preventDefault();

        // do something with values

    }

    return (
        <form onSubmit=(handleSubmit(formSubmit))>
            // the form you have
        </form>
    )

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <form onSubmit=(() => handleSubmit(formSubmit)())>
```

will make it work without adding e.preventDefault()