# Why Does My React Hook Form Still Refresh The Page On Submit

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hook-form

I am trying to make a form and obviously do not want the page to refresh on submit but I am struggling to make this happen. Here's the code:

```
'use client'
import * as React from 'react';
import {useForm} from "react-hook-form"
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';

export default function App() {
    const {register, handleSubmit} = useForm();
  
  return (
    <Box sx={{pt:15}}>
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit((data, e:any): void => {
        console.log(data)
        e.preventDefault()
        
    })}>
        <input {...register("firstName")} placeholder='First Name'/>
        <input {...register("lastName")} placeholder='Last Name'/>
        <input type='submit'/>
    </form>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

I have tried messing aorund with slight changes but nothinfg seems to be working. Any ideas on what I am doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: I think this not accepted answer solves what you want: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68940483/6087422

Answer (score 0):

`react-hook-form` handles the `preventDefault()` automatically so you dont need to explicitly call it.

```
export default function App() {
    const {register, handleSubmit} = useForm();
  
    const onSubmit = (data) => {
        console.log(data);
    };
  
    return (
        <Box sx={{pt:15}}>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
                <input {...register("firstName")} placeholder='First Name'/>
                <input {...register("lastName")} placeholder='Last Name'/>
                <input type='submit'/>
            </form>
        </Box>
    );
}
```

Comment: I thought so too, but even using the code above the page still refreshed on submit for some reason

Comment: Can you share more code please

Comment: For that page, that is the entire code. My other pages don't use forms at all.

Answer (score 0):

Try placing the onSubmit handler function in a `useCallback`, or if there are other data that you're sure wouldn't change you can memoize it. So react wouldn't re-render unnecessarily for those methods or functions.

```
'use client'
import * as React from 'react';
import {useForm} from "react-hook-form"
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';

export default function App() {
  const {register, handleSubmit} = useForm();
  const onSubmit = React.useCallback((data, e:any): void => {
        console.log(data)
        e.preventDefault()
        
  }, [])
  

  return (
    <Box sx={{pt:15}}>
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        <input {...register("firstName")} placeholder='First Name'/>
        <input {...register("lastName")} placeholder='Last Name'/>
        <input type='submit'/>
    </form>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

https://react.dev/reference/react/useCallback
https://react.dev/reference/react/useMemo
https://react.dev/reference/react/useMemo#skipping-re-rendering-of-components